# Put frame on top of another frame

Tags: javascript, html

[image: menu design]i want to use a vertical dropdown menu. Like this.

But I have two frames, and the final result look like this:[image: final result] it's like the frame 1  was on top of frame 2. It's possible to put frame 2 on top frame 1? How can I achieve that my vertical drop down looks like the first pic?

```
<FRAMESET COLS="155,*" FRAMEBORDER="NO" BORDER="0" FRAMESPACING="0">

            <FRAME SRC="menu.php" NAME="lateral" SCROLLING="NO" NORESIZE>
            <FRAME SRC="mainpage.php" NAME="mainFrame" SCROLLING="yes">

        </FRAMESET>
```

menu.php is frame 2 and mainpage.php is frame 1. I don't have much experience on frames.

Answer (score 0):

Set your styles for FRAMESET & FRAME accordingly

For FRAMESET, use

`position:relative`

For FRAME, use

```
position:absolute
z-index: ;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

And adjust your frames to place one on top of the other.

Set the Z-index for your Frame2 higher than Frame1

Now to place your sub nav to collapse below, you can set the Sub nav position relative to the option you are hovering.

Comment: `<FRAMESET COLS="155,*" FRAMEBORDER="NO" BORDER="0" FRAMESPACING="0" style="position:relative">
                
                <FRAME SRC="menu.php" NAME="lateral" SCROLLING="NO" NORESIZE style="position:absolute;z-index:100;top:0;left:0;">
                <FRAME SRC="mainpage.php" NAME="mainFrame" SCROLLING="yes" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1;top:0;left:0;">

            </FRAMESET>` i put this code, with the same result.